# Modification of duplicate items in list box

Tags: c#, winforms

Few duplicate items were added in Listbox how to rename the duplicate items with unique name?

for example listbox is having items

```
Apple 
Orange
mango
Apple
Apple
```

How to rename the items name inside listbox so that output should be

```
Apple
Orange
mango
Apple#1
Apple#2
```

Comment: How are you adding the items to the list in the first place? One at a time or all in one go?

Comment: Adding All item in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//// convert listBox items to string
var listBoxItems = listBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

/// find duplicate Items
var duplicateKeys = listBoxItems.GroupBy(x => x)
                        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                        .Select(c => new { value = c.Key, count = c.Count() });

//// generate duplicate item +index number
foreach (var duplicateItem in duplicateKeys)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < duplicateItem.count; i++)
    {
      if (listBoxItems.Contains(duplicateItem.value))
      {
         listBoxItems.Remove(duplicateItem.value);
      }

      if (i == 0)
       {
         listBoxItems.Add(duplicateItem.value);
       }
       else
       {
         listBoxItems.Add(duplicateItem.value + i);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: for '+index number', wouldn't it be `(duplicateItem.value + i)`?

Comment: Is it going to modify the existing items in list box or else i have to the items add again after execution of above code? I think output is something like apple1 instead of apple#1.

Comment: @kumar it generates a `List<string>` of items than you can bind `listBoxItems` to ListBox. yes i thought #1 means index you could just change `listBoxItems.Add(duplicateItem.value + i)`; to `listBoxItems.Add(duplicateItem.value +"#"+ i);`